# What is the reason for this panic?

Tags: go, segmentation-fault

For practicing some of the basic concepts I'm writing a simple port scanner. When trying to implement goroutines however, the program panics and I get a segmentation fault:

```
Scanning ports
{Port:139 State:Open}
{Port:135 State:Open}
{Port:136 State:Closed}
{Port:131 State:Closed}
{Port:131 State:Open}
{Port:134 State:Closed}
{Port:134 State:Open}
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x4eb26a]

goroutine 20 [running]:
main.scanPort(0x52033b, 0x3, 0x52203e, 0xf, 0x83)
        /home/athos/Projects/go-tutorial/scanner.go:33 +0x1ea
created by main.main
        /home/athos/Projects/go-tutorial/scanner.go:41 +0xf1
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x4eb26a]

goroutine 23 [running]:
main.scanPort(0x52033b, 0x3, 0x52203e, 0xf, 0x86)
        /home/athos/Projects/go-tutorial/scanner.go:33 +0x1ea
created by main.main
        /home/athos/Projects/go-tutorial/scanner.go:41 +0xf1
exit status 2
```

This is my code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "strconv"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup

type scanResult struct {
    Port  int
    State string
}

func scanPort(protocol, hostname string, port int) {
    defer wg.Done()
    result := scanResult{Port: port}
    socket := hostname + ":" + strconv.Itoa(port)
    conn, err := net.DialTimeout(protocol, socket, 2*time.Second)

    if err != nil {
        result.State = "Closed"
        fmt.Printf("%+v\n", result)
    }

    result.State = "Open"
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", result)

    // Defers: FILO data structure
    defer conn.Close()
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Scanning ports")
    for i := 130; i <= 145; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go scanPort("tcp", "192.168.200.103", i)
    }
    // Wait for goroutines to complete
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Can anyone help me see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: maybe add `return` when you handle the error? Because, if an error occurs,  `conn` will probably be `nil`.

Comment: From counting the line numbers, it appears that `conn.Close()` is called when `conn` is `nil`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`net.DialTimeout()` returns a connection and an error, You properly check if the error is not `nil`, but even if there is an error, you just print it and continue.

If there is a non-`nil` error, you should not (must not) use the returned connection, as that may be `nil` or an invalid value. If there is an error, inspect / print it and return, do not attempt to use `conn`.

So simply return:

```
if err != nil {
    result.State = "Closed"
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", result)
    return
}
```

Also if there is no error, you may "schedule" closing the connection immediately, deferred. There is no point using `defer` if you close the connection last thing in the function.

So it should be something like this:

```
conn, err := net.DialTimeout(protocol, socket, 2*time.Second)

if err != nil {
    result.State = "Closed"
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", result)
    return
}

defer conn.Close()

result.State = "Open"
fmt.Printf("%+v\n", result)
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks.